# Subtrair dois TIMESTAMP e receber o valor em minutos no Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Como `subtrair` dois campos `TIMESTAMP` e receber o valor em `minutos` no [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle)?

```
DATAFIM - DATAINICIO = 2880 minutos (ou dois dias)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dada uma tabela `T` com dois campos do tipo `TIMESTAMP`, `t1` e `t2`:

```sql
create table T (t1 timestamp, t2 timestamp);
```

Podemos calcular a diferença em minutos extraindo e somando os diferentes componentes do intervalor resultado da subtração `t2 - t1`:

```
select 
  extract(day from intervalo) * 60 * 24 +  --minutos dos dias do intervalo
  extract(hour from intervalo) * 60 +  --minutos das horas do intervalo
  extract(minute from intervalo) --minutos do intervalo
from (select t2 - t1 intervalo from T);
```

## Explicação

Como a subtração de dois campos `DATE` ou `TIMESTAMP` resulta num `INTERVAL`, podemos então extrair e somar os componentes relevantes desse intervalo (dias, horas, minutos), ignorando os irreletantes (segundos e milissegundos).

Comment: Estranho apliquei a sua idéia, mas o cálculo saiu errado. O cálculo da DATAFIM (23/04/14 08:21:32,819000000) - DATAINICIO (23/04/14 08:13:55,261000000) resultou 16 quando deveria retornar 8.

Comment: A sua solução funcionou perfeitamente. O erro foi meu aqui.

Comment: A solução: SELECT extract(day from 24*60*(DATAFIM - DATAINICIO)) AS intervalo FROM minha_table me atendeu, mas vou dar sua resposta como certa.

Comment: @GeisonSantos Você é livre para dar como certa a resposta que preferir. Não se prenda por quem respondeu ou pela ordem das respostas. ;)

Answer (score 2):

A resposta para essa pergunta eu pegue **[deste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063214/convert-interval-to-minutes)** do **SOEn**

Se você multiplicar o intervalo por 24 e por 60, você obtem o número de minutos extraindo o número de dias. É mais compacto, mas não tenho certeza se seria mais elegante do seu ponto de vista.

```
SQL> create table t (meu_intervalo interval day to second)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> insert into t
  2  select numtodsinterval(30,'minute') from dual union all
  3  select numtodsinterval(4,'hour') from dual
  4  /

2 rows created.

SQL> select meu_intervalo 
  2       , 60 * extract(hour from meu_intervalo )
  3         + extract(minute from meu_intervalo ) minutes_terrible_way
  4       , extract(day from 24*60*meu_intervalo ) minutes_other_way
  5    from t
  6  /

meu_intervalo                   MINUTES_TERRIBLE_WAY MINUTES_OTHER_WAY
------------------------------ -------------------- -----------------
+00 00:30:00.000000                              30                30
+00 04:00:00.000000                             240               240

2 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com essa [Thread da Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/381913?start=0&tstart=0) todas as datas são números também:

> if you make operations between dates the result is a number

E como o **rsenna** indicou, seus campos são `TIMESTAMP` que devem ser convertidos antes de serem utilizados em operações matematicas.

Logo podemos fazer:

```
(CAST(DATAFIM AS DATE) * 1440) - (CAST(DATAINICIO AS DATE) * 1440)
```

Odeio números mágicos mas o `1440` ali é o número de minutos em um dia

Comment: Tentei sua abordagem, mas obtive um erro 'ORA-00932: tipos de dados inconsistentes: esperava NUMBER obteve TIMESTAMP'

Comment: @SparK @GeisonSantos Na verdade todos os campos dos tipos `DATE` são números também. Mas campos do tipo `TIMESTAMP` são "objetos", não podem ser subtraídos com tanta facilidade, e é necessário um cast antes. Utilizando a ideia do SparK, a seguinte consulta funcionaria: `SELECT (CAST(T1 AS DATE) - CAST(T2 AS DATE)) * 1440 FROM T`.

Comment: Segue um [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9d9d/2/0) pra provar que a subtração funciona.

Comment: @rsenna, valeu pelo esclarecimento. Muito boa sua dica sobre o sqlfiddle; desconhecia.

Comment: opa @rsenna vou corrigir, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Por meio das respostas dadas pelos colegas cheguei a minha própria resposta. Não é a melhor ou mais elaborada, mas sim uma síntese, uma simplificação e que foi postada para o conhecimento da solução adotada.

**Estrutura da tabela:**

```
CREATE TABLE T (DT_INICIO timestamp, DT_FIM timestamp);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (
  TO_DATE('2014/04/01 19:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
  TO_DATE('2014/04/01 19:15:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

**Solução para o problema:**

```
SELECT extract(day from 24 * 60 * (DT_FIM - DT_INICIO )) as MINUTOS FROM T;
```